# Convergence in Law for Sum of gamma variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{gamma}(\alpha , \text{scale}=\theta )$.
Let $Y_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. I have found that for each positive integer $n$, $Y_n \sim \text{gamma}(n\alpha ,\beta )$ (using moment generating functions).

I am now asked to find two constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that $$\sqrt{n} \left ( Y_n - c_1 \right ) \overset{L}{\longrightarrow} \text{N}(0,c_2) .$$

My first thought is to quote central limit theorem, but that is only defined with sample means. I also attempted to use moment generating functions, but I had trouble with the $\sqrt{n}$ affecting when the moment generating functions exist finitely.

If anyone can give a suggestion, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You can use the central limit theorem or moment generating functions, but you should tidy up some issues, such as choosing to use scale $\theta$ or rate $\beta$, and deciding whether $Y_n$ is the mean or sum of the $X_i$; if the latter then you should be aiming to show  $\sqrt{n} \left ( \frac1n Y_n - c_1 \right ) \overset{L}{\longrightarrow} \text{N}(0,c_2)$ or something similar